Stable Diffusion 3 does not work with diffusers
I try to use Stable Diffusion 3 on my desktop.
But it doesn't work.
I make the test.py file, the file is mostly same as sample code on Hugging Face.
Difference is only about authentication. The sample has no authentication statement.
import torch
from diffusers import StableDiffusion3Pipeline

token="MY_TOKEN";

pipe = StableDiffusion3Pipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3-medium-diffusers", use_auth_token=token,torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")

image = pipe(
            "A cat holding a sign that says hello world",
            negative_prompt="",
            num_inference_steps=28,
            guidance_scale=7.0,
        ).images[0]
image

Run time error -
Couldn't connect to the Hub: 401 Client Error. (Request ID: Root=1-669607ff-38d1dce957780f8d7ffc71bf;be997e6a-4dc6-40ac-9c95-35346e6c2fef)

Cannot access gated repo for url https://huggingface.co/api/models/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3-medium-diffusers.
Access to model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3-medium-diffusers is restricted. You must be authenticated to access it..
Will try to load from local cache.
Keyword arguments {'use_auth_token': 'MY_TOKEN'} are not expected by StableDiffusion3Pipeline and will be ignored.

MY_TOKEN is my hugging face access token.
I ask ChatGPT then he said a kind of authentication problem. he could not resolve the problem.
Please let me know what I should do.
I tried to exchange 'use_auth_token' to 'auth_token', but nothing change.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I used to have the exact same issue with 3.5 model. Upon some trial and error it appears that the use_auth_token argument might be already deprecated.
However I managed to resolve the issue by following steps here:
https://stability.ai/learning-hub/setting-up-and-using-sd3-medium-locally
In particular I executed huggingface-cli login from the console with the same virtualenv as my jupyter runtime. It asks you to paste the token to console and confirm a few details. Upon restarting the runtime a plain command went withnout any issues:
pipe = diffusers.StableDiffusion3Pipeline.from_pretrained(
    "stabilityai/stable-diffusion-3.5-medium",
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

